# What’s wrong with my snake plant leaves?

Tags: plant-care, diseases, watering, fungus, dryness

I recently discovered the tip of my snake plant had turned blackish and cut off from the rest of the plant, basically dead, the dead part feels moist and floppy.

I don’t know what’s wrong if I’m under watering or overwatering or root rot, please help.
I include pictures below of it.

[image: Leaf with darkened tip]

[image: Leaf with darkened tip]

Comment: Please add to the question how often do you water, what kind of pot you use, what kind of soil mixture you have and how well lit area the plant resides.

Comment: I suspect over watering based on the symptoms.

Comment: have you a pet, like a cat? or young children? not sure this isn't physical damage...